# What does 不死議 mean?

Tags: grammar, nuances, song-lyrics

I was translating a song when this lyric showed up

> 100回落ちても不死議は鳥乱さない

不死議 is not one word. But I'm having trouble breaking it down in this context. Is this a saying that I don't know?

Here's [the song in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfVWqos23xs) for more context.

Comment: 不死議 sounds the same as actual word 不思議 ("wonderful, marvelous, strange, incredible, amazing, curious, miraculous, mysterious"). Maybe it is some joke on that word... (不死 means "immortality, eternal life, undeath, undead".)

Comment: This song has a lot of wordplay so maybe that is the case?

Comment: For translation, I do not know what better fits context, but maybe you could combine definitions of both words and use "wonderful immortality", "wonderful undead" or something...

Comment: @Arfrever I don't think this sentence can be correctly translated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a wordplay and it only exists in the song トンデモワンダーズ.
「ふしぎ」 is written 不思議 but the second kanji (思{し}) is replaced with 死{し}.
[取り乱す]{とりみだす} also has one kanji replaced (鳥{とり}) so I'm guessing it might have something to do with a 不死鳥 (a Phoenix)?